SettingWithCopyWarning error when creating a column on a sliced dataframe
I am investigating the strictness of referees across the top 5 leagues in football (soccer), and have received the above error when trying to create a new "Strictness" column on multiple slices of a dataframe.
I have an original dataframe called "ref_data" which contains information on a load of different referees, such as the league they're from, number of matches reffed, yellow and red cards brandished and more. I then have a bunch of smaller slices of the dataframe which are categorised by season and league, stored in an array called "dfs", where:
dfs = [refs_prem2425, refs_prem2324, refs_prem2223, refs_laliga2425, etc...]
The smaller slices were created through boolean masks. Example:
refs_prem2425 = ref_data[(ref_data["League"] == "Premier League") & (ref_data["Season"] == "24/25")]

When trying to create the new column "Strictness" on these smaller dataframes, I am met with the SettingWithCopyWarning error and I cannot figure out how to fix it. The code I am currently using is:
for df in dfs:
    for referee in df["Referee"]:
        df["Strictness%"] = ((df["Booking Points Per Match"]/(df["Total Booking Points"].sum()/df["Number of Matches"].sum()))*100).round(1)

The calculation is basically comparing the Referee's average rate of showing cards, to the League's rate that season. There is likely an easier way to do this without dividing the original dataframe, but I am fairly new to programming so that is beyond me.
The above code outputs the values on the smaller dataframes in a new column titled "Strictness", which is what I want, however I can't seem to get rid of the error. I have read up on ways to remove the error through...
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

...but have heard it is strongly recommended to fix the error instead.
Like I said, pretty new to all this so there may be an easy fix or I may not have provided enough information.

Add .copy() onto the end of your dataframe slices
